# Oozie: propagate-configuration does not work

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, oozie, orchestration

I may be missing something since `propagate-configuration` does not seem to be working for me.

I have a base workflow `base.xml`, with configuration:

```xml
<global>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <job-xml>application-config.xml</job-xml>   
    <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>paths.prefix.metadata</name>
            <value>${nameNode}${fimProcessingMetadataPath}</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
</global>
```

And in this very file, I have sub-workflows defined like this:

```xml
<action name="srv_a">
    <sub-workflow>
        <app-path>${nameNode}${workflowPath}/a.xml</app-path>
        <propagate-configuration />
    </sub-workflow>
    <ok to="b" />
    <error to="kill" />
</action>
<action name="srv_b">
    <sub-workflow>
        <app-path>${nameNode}${workflowPath}/b.xml</app-path>
        <propagate-configuration />
    </sub-workflow>
    <ok to="c" />
    <error to="kill" />
</action>
// Here there are many sub-workflows like these.
```

But then in my code, I cannot find the `paths.prefix.metadata` property - it fails to find it.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mandatory property property is not set.     
Please provide paths.prefix.metadata
```

If I define it again in `a.xml` as its own property, I can access it OK.

So, how can I propagate this variable from `base.xml` definition to the sub-workflows? As I understand from the [documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.6_Sub-workflow_Action):

> The propagate-configuration flag, if present, indicates that the workflow job configuration should be propagated to the child workflow.

But it does not seem to reach the child workflow. Why? Is it not an expected behaviour that the global configuration is not propagated to the child sub-workflows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. After some scrambling, the workaround I found working is to add a configuration section within sub-workflow in base xml. The properties inside the config section will be passed down to sub-workflow, e.g.:

```xml
...
<action name="srv_b">
  <sub-workflow>
    <app-path>a.xml</app-path>
    <propagate-configuration />
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>paths.prefix.metadata</name>
        <value>${nameNode}${fimProcessingMetadataPath}</value>
      </property>
      ...
    </configuration>
  </sub-workflow>
</action>
```

Comment: OK, this does not seem obvious from Oozie documentation. It is an enhancement to what I have finally done, though.

Answer (score 0):

works only for passing the job.properties file.
to pass variables of global section to subworkflow, we need to pass inside the 
 section of the subworkflow.